# RoR generated sql has where

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 3 tables stauscode, worequest and employee.  Worequest belongs to employee and employee has_many worequests.  Worequest belongs to statuscode and statuscode has many worequests.

I also have a scope for worequest:

```
   scope :notcompl, where(:statuscode_id != Statuscode.last, true)
```

I'm trying to display the worequests for the employee that are not completed:

```
 <% @employee.worequests.notcompl.each do |worequest| %>
```

The error I get:
G::Error: ERROR:  argument of AND must be type boolean, not type integer
LINE 1: ...uests"  WHERE "worequests"."employee_id" = 2 AND (1) ORDER B...

I'm trying to view employee number 2.  I can't figure out why it's putting the "and (1)" into the SQL.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: The SQL being generated is - : SELECT "worequests".* FROM "worequests"  WHERE "worequests"."employee_id" = 2 AND (1) ORDER BY id DESC.  I can't figure out why the AND (1) is thrown into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your scope

```
   scope :notcompl, where(:statuscode_id != Statuscode.last, true)
```

Is broken. Unlike some ruby orms, activerecord doesn't override methods on symbols, so that where just ends up being

```
where(true,true)
```

(since clearly that symbol is never equal to an integer) and true is being typecast to the integer 1. If you want to find rows where somethin isn't equal to something else you need to do

```
where("status_code_id != ?", StatusCode.last.id)
```

Also note that this will use what the last status code was at the point where the file with this scope in was loaded - you'll want to wrap the scope in a lambda if your app creates status codes as it's running

Comment: I changed it to:     scope :notcompl, where("statuscode_id != ?", Statuscode.last.id) and it worked.  THANKS

Answer (score 0):

Have you missed specifying `compelted` (`status`?) column name? If so, you should rewrite your scope:

```
scope :notcompl, where("statuscode_id != #{Statuscode.last.id}").where(completed: true)
```

Comment: No, the last status code is completed.  Completed is not another column.  Maybe it should be - have to think about that.

Comment: PS - the scope works OK when I'm just listing completed or not completed worequests.